# CountBy WithCriteria does not match

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Using a countBy (or dynamic finder) does not give a result, but withCriteria does.

This is the class:

```
class Message {

    EntityType entityType
    String code

}
```

then:

```
assert 1 == Message.countByCodeAndEntityType("category.name.${result.id}", EntityType.APPLICATION_TEXT)
```

returns 0 (false assertion) but...

```
assert 1 == Message.createCriteria().list(){
            eq ("code", "category.name.${result.id}")
            eq ("entityType",EntityType.APPLICATION_TEXT)
            projections{
                count()
            }
        }[0]
```

gives a correct result returning 1

whats is the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked if ${result.id} is correctly resolved in both variants?

How looks the SQL?

For Counting I prefer this:

```
Message.createCriteria().count(){
    eq ("code", "category.name.${result.id}")
    eq ("entityType",EntityType.APPLICATION_TEXT)
}
```

Comment: I guess It is resolving it, cause I replace one for the other, so ${result.id} always exists. Furthermore, using the debugger is the same. The criteria result is the correct. I have one record in my db, but count does not work

Answer (score 0):

See documentation : https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html

**count**   Returns the count of the given property name

So you need to use rowCount() in projections
Enjoy!)

Comment: rowCount and count give the same result in this case, the problem is countBy returns 0 instead of 1

Comment: @kix300zx only if you haven't empty value.. In your case better to use rowCount()

Comment: @kix300zx and if you read documentation, you need to insert field name in the count()

Comment: Thanks but the problem is not there, is here  Message.countByCodeAndEntityType("category.name.${result.id}", EntityType.APPLICATION_TEXT)

Comment: @kix300zx I think problem in EntityType. If you save entityType in db, try to receive it, if not - try to replace it to message class how enum